# How to fix "The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'ProduktList'"

Tags: dart, flutter

I get the following error:

> The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty): type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'ProduktList'

When i press on an IconButton i want to see a new Page. The new Page needs a Product List. These List i get with the Function addToCart.

My Navigator:

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Einkaufswagen(produktList: addToCart(),)
                )
            );
          }
      ),
```

The addToCart Function:

```
addToCart() async{
CollectionReference collectionReference =  Firestore.instance.collection("Benutzer").document("Anton").collection("Einkaufsliste").reference();
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.getDocuments();
List<Produkt> produktList = [];


for(int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.documents.length; i++){
  ProduktList produkte = ProduktList.fromJson(querySnapshot.documents[i].data);
  for(int j = 0; j < produkte.produkte.length; j++){
    if(produkte.produkte[j].anzahl > 0 && produkte.produkte[j].isChecked) {
      print("Item to produktList: " + produkte.produkte[j].name);
      produktList.add(produkte.produkte[j]);
      print("Items in produktList: " + produktList.toString() + " Anzahl: " + produktList.length.toString());
    }
  }
}

ProduktList toCart = ProduktList(produkte: produktList);
print("ToCart: " + toCart.produkte.length.toString());
return toCart;
}
```

The Class Einkaufswagen:

```
class Einkaufswagen extends StatefulWidget {
  Einkaufswagen({this.produktList});

  ProduktList produktList;

  @override
  _EinkaufswagenState createState() => _EinkaufswagenState();
}

class _EinkaufswagenState extends State<Einkaufswagen> {
  _EinkaufswagenState({this.produktList});

  ProduktList produktList;

      getCartItems(){
     print(produktList);
     List<CheckboxListTile> listTile = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      listTile.add(
        CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text("Pimmel"),
          value: true,
          onChanged: null,
        )
      );
    }

    return listTile;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Build");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Einkaufswagen"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Column(
                    children: getCartItems(),
                  );
                },
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I dont know how to fix this Error. Maybe u can give me some advices how to do it better.
Thank you for help.

**EDIT:**

```
class Einkaufswagen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<ProduktList> produktList;

  Einkaufswagen2({this.produktList});

  myCheckBoxListTile(int index, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(snapshot.data.produkte[index].name),
      value: snapshot.data.produkte[index].isChecked,
      onChanged: (value){
        print("Tap! " + snapshot.data.produkte[index].name);
        snapshot.data.produkte[index].isChecked = value;
        print("IsChecked: " + snapshot.data.produkte[index].isChecked.toString());
      },
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      secondary: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: (){

              }
          ),
          Text(snapshot.data.produkte[index].anzahl.toString()),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: (){
                snapshot.data.produkte[index].anzahl--;
                print(snapshot.data.produkte[index].anzahl);
              }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Einkaufswagen"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future:  produktList,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            switch (snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.waiting :  return CircularProgressIndicator();
              default:
                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                  return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                } else{
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.produkte.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return myCheckBoxListTile(index, snapshot);
                    }
                  );
                }
            }
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this Stateless Class it Works but it didnt change the view when i tap on something, i think because stateless and i dont know how to implement in Stateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the way you are using the Future.

First, it's better to change the addToCart function to return a Future of Produkts:

```
Future<List<Product>> addToCart() async{
   ...
}
```

Apart from that, you are passing the Future to the other Widget:

```
Einkaufswagen(produktList: addToCart(),)
```

You need to resolve this `Future` to get the actual list not a Future of it. the best way is using a FutureBuilder in the widget:

```
return new FutureBuilder(
    future: addToCart(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError)
          {
            return new Center(child: Text('Some warning'));
          }
          else {
            return  new ListBuilder(snapshot.data)
            }
      }
    },
);
```

You can find more here: [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: i think something like that. addToCart is a Function in my statefull class HomePage. i want to call addToCart with an other Class Constructor, to use it on an other Page. At this Time i try the FutureBuilder in a StatelessClass Einkaufswagen. How to use this in a StatefulClass? Because i want to use a Variable of Produktlist in a CheckboxListTile. In the Stateless Class the view dont change when i tap on the Checkboxlisttile