# What is "dirty" in Flutter & what is causing this "dirty" state?

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-getx

I am trying to learn both state management & dependancy injection with this demo project. I'm trying to demo injecting some methods all over the place like I may need to in my program. I'm using GetX because I like being able to do this without context in non-widget classes.

So my problem here is the last method, summationReturns(), in the last class below. Attempts to take methods with return statements and add them together. I call this in two places. In the floating button, this works fine but in my text widget I get a dirty state error.

Why is this not working when everything else works? And I assume this will be a corollary from the last question, what is a dirty state? Seems like two questions but I would imagine that they are one in the same.

```
///
///
/// DEMO PROJECT WORKING OUT GETX
/// WORKOUT DEPENDANCY INJECTION AND STATE MANAGEMENT

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/get_state_manager.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  // Injection of dependancy
  final Controller controller = Get.put(Controller());
  final Observable observable = Get.put(Observable());
  final SimpleMath simpleMath = Get.put(SimpleMath());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Get builders:'),
            GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (controller) {
              return Text(controller.count.toString());
            }),
            GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (controller) {
              return Text(controller.countList.toString());
            }),
            GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (controller) {
              return Text(controller.returnCount().toString());
            }),
            GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (controller) {
              return Text(controller.returnList().toString());
            }),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text('Get observables:'),
            Obx(() => Text(observable.count.value.toString())),
            Obx(() => Text(observable.countList.value.toString())),
            Obx(() => Text(observable.returnCount().toString())),
            Obx(() => Text(observable.returnList().toString())),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text('Get from other class:'),
            GetBuilder<SimpleMath>(builder: (simpleMath) {
              return Text('Variable summation: ' + simpleMath.summationVariables().toString());
            }),
            GetBuilder<SimpleMath>(builder: (simpleMath) {
              return Text(simpleMath.summationReturns().toString());
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.crunch();
          observable.crunch();
          simpleMath.summationVariables();
          simpleMath.summationReturns();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Controller extends GetxController {
  int count = 0;
  List<int> countList = [];

  void crunch() {
    count += 1;
    countList.add(count);
    update();
  }

  int returnCount() {
    return count;
  }

  List<int> returnList() {
    return countList;
  }
}

class Observable extends GetxController {
  RxInt count = 0.obs;
  Rx<RxList> countList = RxList().obs;

  void crunch() {
    count.value += 1;
    countList.value.add(count.value);
  }

  int returnCount() {
    return count.value;
  }

  List<dynamic> returnList() {
    return countList.value.toList();
  }
}

class SimpleMath extends GetxController {
  final Controller controller = Get.find<Controller>();
  final Observable observable = Get.find<Observable>();

  int summationVariables() {
    int sum = controller.count + observable.count.value;
    update();
    return sum;
  }

  int summationReturns() {
    int sum = controller.returnCount() + observable.returnCount();
    print('Summation of return values: ' + sum.toString());
    update();
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building GetBuilder<SimpleMath>(dirty, state:
GetBuilderState<SimpleMath>#4d62d):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This GetBuilder<SimpleMath> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during
the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed
because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will
always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  GetBuilder<SimpleMath>
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  GetBuilder<SimpleMath>

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  GetBuilder<SimpleMath>
  file:///Users/robertobuttazzoni/Documents/Flutter%20Tutorials/Flutter%20Learning/getx_basics/getx_basics/lib/main.dart:57:13
```

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594133/how-to-fix-the-error-the-following-assertion-was-thrown-building-futurebuilder , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720990/how-to-fix-this-error-the-following-assertion-was-thrown-building-futurebuilder , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182514/how-to-fix-the-following-assertion-was-thrown-building-builderdirty-type-fu

Comment: InsaneCat, I'm not sure how to apply these answers. They do in fact look like the same issue, however how do they apply to the GetBuilder? For example I tried this in the get builder with no luck: ``` if (simpleMath.isEmpty) return widget -- else return progressIndicator``` Also why do the other similar method calls work but not this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `update` while build is ongoing is an example of dirty scenario. To fix your issue, do not call `update` inside the `GetBuilder`.

Sample...

In Home

```
GetBuilder<SimpleMath>(
    builder: (simpleMath) => Text('Variable summation: ' +
        simpleMath
            .summationVariables(shouldUpdate: false)
            .toString())),
GetBuilder<SimpleMath>(
    builder: (simpleMath) => Text(simpleMath
        .summationReturns(shouldUpdate: false)
        .toString())),
```

In SimpleMath

```
int summationVariables({bool shouldUpdate = true}) {
  int sum = controller.count + observable.count.value;
  if (shouldUpdate) update();
  return sum;
}

int summationReturns({bool shouldUpdate = true}) {
  int sum = controller.returnCount() + observable.returnCount();
  print('Summation of return values: ' + sum.toString());
  if (shouldUpdate) update();
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I get the same error with this application. I also tried removing the update() completely from both methods and still does not work. Same error both attempts. I think I will simply figure out a work around. Still this is mysterious to me that all these other methods work except the last one. Is it possible that the controller.returnCount() or the observable.returnCount() is not finished while it's being called again? But this also does not explain the fact that the other methods calling these methods work...???

Comment: @RobbB Hmm... Works fine on my end. Weird... You're using the latest version of Flutter and GetX right? If yes, can you update the code in your question (w/ my answer) so that I can check it on my end?

Comment: super weird. Finally had time to try this again. This time I copy pasted your code exactly as is and it works like a charm! Really strange. Only difference is when I tried before I used brackets and a return statement. Anyway thanks for the help dude!